# how to automatically create lists in python, I want to classify a series of values ​in intervals

Tags: python

For example, if I have a range of values ​​from `0` to `55` and I want to create intervals every `5`, then `55/5 = 11` I want python to generate `11` empty lists that I can fill, how can i create it automatically?

The context is, to distribute some measures of wind to be able to carry out a weibull distribution

For more detail, I have speed measurements throughout a year, so if the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 55 (it can be any number) and I want to divide into intervals of 5 (km/h) to know how long it blows At what rate throughout the year?

So I want it to create as many lists as necessary to fill in with the corresponding values, so I can know how many measures (len) each interval has

I have tried a few things but all failed

Comment: Welcome to SO. _I have tried a few things but all failed_ - it's best to show your attempt, even if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very automated, but may be a starting point.

### Code

```
spds = [0,1,2,2,4,5,5,10,9,8,11,12,1,15,4,6,13] #rand data 0-15km
placehold = []
spds.sort()                                     #sort low->high
low = spds[0]                                   #lowest
high = spds[len(spds)-1]                        #highest
intr = 5
lsts = int(high / intr)                         #15/5

for i in range(0, lsts):           #num of lists/intervals
  placehold.append(i)
  
for a in placehold.copy():         
  if type(placehold[a]) != list:   
    placehold[a] = []              #create lists for each

for b in spds.copy():              
    if b >= 0 and b <= 5:          #sort vals by interval
      placehold[0].append(b)
      spds.remove(b)
        
    elif b > 5 and b <= 10:        #(0-5km), (10-15km) etc.
      placehold[1].append(b)
      spds.remove(b)
      
    elif b > 10 and b <=15:
      placehold[2].append(b)
      spds.remove(b)
      
      
print(placehold)
```

### Result

A list of lists with entries grouped by interval.

`[[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5], [6, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 15]]`

(0-5km)

[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5]

(5-10km)

[6, 8, 9, 10]

(10-15km)

[11, 12, 13, 15]

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer me

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function in Python takes three parameters: the initial number, the ending number, and the interval. Using this, you can loop through this range to create the list of arrays that you want like so:

```py
initial = 0
end = 56 # This is not inclusive, so we must add one to 55
interval = 5

L = [[] for i in range(initial, end, interval)] # Creates a list of empty lists
print(L)
```

This results in `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer me